# Angularjs in Node-Webkit function lose $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node-webkit

I've this simple controller in an application developed in Node-Webkit with angular:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('antApp')
    .controller('StartMenuController', StartMenuController);

function StartMenuController($scope, $rootScope, $state){
    var self = $scope;
    self.app = $rootScope;

    self.init = init;
    self.startGame = startGame;

    init();

    function init(){

    };

    function startGame (){
        $state.go('main');
    };
};
```

})();

The strange thing (to me) is, when i click on the "StartGame" button in the html:

```
<div id="startMenuPage" class="container-fluid full-page">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="text-align: center">
        <a ng-click="startGame()" class="btn btn-info sound-button">New Game</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "`self`" variable, that is a reference to `$scope` is replaced by the "`window`" object of the browser (nw) itself. Even `$scope` and `$rootScope` but this is not the case for the `$state` variable.

This scenario is a common one that I've used many times when developing proper web application and I'm sure I'm missing something on the NW part.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem.  I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/) and it works fine.  Only thing was I had to change .module to `.module('antApp', []);`  Can you recreate the problem in a Fiddle?

Comment: Thank you Jacob! I fogot to mention that I'm using ui.router, can this be the reason why I'm not passing the scope to the variable?

Comment: Forgot to mention, in common web environment (node/iis with common browser, everything works as expectedm your fiddle too

Comment: this kind of code design is a bit backwards.  if you use the `ControllerAs` syntax, the `controller` is added as an object directly onto the scope where the controller is bound.  this gives you `$scope.controller.property`, or `controller.property` in the HTML, where `$scope` is implied.   your controller can then use `self = this`, and have your properties automatically be `$scope.controller` bound, without needing to reference `$scope` at all.

Comment: Thanks Claies, I just converted to the ControllerAs syntax fully but the problem still persists. It seems that Node-Webkit get rid entirely of the context where the function itself lives

Comment: Ok, a bit more details. The problem seems related only to angular called function. In fact, if I bind the "click" with javascript, inside the function all the controllers variables are working properly